# Avoiding recursion in toString method

Tags: java, tostring, overriding

this is my huge mindblowing problem with a Java exercise. So, we've got this:

```
public class CyclicEmployee {
    private int age;
    private String name;
    private CyclicEmployee boss;
    private List<CyclicEmployee> subordinate
}
```

and our goal is to overwrite toString method by cutting fields which may lead to recursive infinity. Finally it's supposed to look like a printed  object with a name, age, boss and subordinate.

```
Employee[age=30,name='Mike',boss=Employee[age=45,name='Ann'], subordinate=[Employee[age=25,name='Jimmy']]]
```

Well, I tried and found that i have no clue how to deal with toString overriding:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CyclicEmployee {
    private int age;
    private String name;
    private CyclicEmployee boss;
    private List<CyclicEmployee> subordinate ;

public CyclicEmployee(int age, String name) {
    this.age=age;
    this.name=name;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  CyclicEmployee Mike = new CyclicEmployee(33,"Mike");
  Mike.boss = new CyclicEmployee(44,"Ann");
  Mike.subordinate = new ArrayList<CyclicEmployee>();
  Mike.subordinate.add(new CyclicEmployee(24,"Jim"));
    System.out.println(Mike.toString());
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "CyclicEmployee{" +
            "age=" + age +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", boss=" + boss +
            ", subordinate=" + subordinate +
            '}';
    }

}CyclicEmployee{age=33, name='Mike', boss=CyclicEmployee{age=44, name='Ann', boss=null, subordinate=null}, subordinate=[CyclicEmployee{age=24, name='Jim', boss=null, subordinate=null}]}
```

It seems like I should cut all the "null" fields here, but I can't find the way out.

Comment: Your question is to not get fields that are null or what?

Comment: Briefly -yes, Id like to omit them.

Comment: Have you checked my solution, does that work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you do not want to print null `CyclicEmployee` objects. You can check if `boss` and `subordinates` are null and then if they are skip them in `toString()`. Since all of them are same type, this method will work for all of them.

```
@Override
public String toString() {

String str = "";
str = "CyclicEmployee{" +
    "age=" + age +
    ", name='" + name + '\'';
if (boss != null) {
  str += ", boss=" + boss;
}
if (subordinate.size() != 0) {
  str += ", subordinate=" + subordinate;
}
  str += '}';
return str;
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's it! The only thing, there should be subordinate! =null instead. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, since subordinate is a `list` actually you may not need to check if it is null, I've checked the size of it. If my answer works for you could you please accept and upvote it please.

Comment: I've already tried, but my reputation is low cause i'm newbie here.

Comment: But, I guess you should be able to accept the answer since it is your question. Try to click checkmark near my answer please

Comment: Done. Sorry, the interface is unfamiliar.

Comment: No, you accept the other answer not mine :) Please accept mine :)

Comment: Lol, u are dealing with noob.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using existing data structure like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html) or [this](https://github.com/Scalified/tree) instead.

But if you really want to use your code, you can create a NonCyclicEmployee class

```
private static class NonCyclicEmployee {

    private int age;
    private String name;

    public NonCyclicEmployee(int age, String name) {
        this.age=age;
        this.name=name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CyclicEmployee{" +
            "age=" + age +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            '}';
    }
}
```

And use it in your toString() of CyclicEmployee.

```
private CyclicEmployee boss;
private List<CyclicEmployee> subordinate ;
private NonCyclicEmployee ncBoss;
private List<NonCyclicEmployee> ncSubordinate ;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "CyclicEmployee{" +
        "age=" + age +
        ", name='" + name + '\'' +
        ", boss=" + ncBoss +
        ", subordinate=" + ncSubordinate +
        '}';
}
```

And create a method addBoss() and addSubordinate() to create both bosses (boss and ncBoss) and both subordinate at the same time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will learn TreeModel & try to use it . BTW, could we use something like if-else structure in toString to cut fierlds?